# Match whole string in regex

Tags: php, regex

I have string for example: `hasan عمرانی`.
I want to match persian chars for the whole string. I mean if the string is not entirely persian the regex doesn't match any character.

I have this pattern so far:`[\x{0600}-\x{06FF}\s]+`. but it matches `عمرانی`.
It must not match any of the string.

please help me to provide a pattern.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add `^` at the beginning of your expression and `$` at the end, to try to match from the beginning to the end of the string being searched.

```
^[\x{0600}-\x{06FF}\s]+$
```

Tested it and it works on [Regex101](http://regex101.com/r/aP9rM6)

Answer (score 3):

You can use `\p{Old_Persian}` property instead of range:

```
^\p{Old_Persian}+$
```